# getting "none" as result and don't uderstand why

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

I am learning how to program in python 3 and today i was praticing until i start to struggle with this.
I was trying to make a function to get to know the total square meters of wood that i'll use in one project, but i keep get the none result and i don't know why, even reading almost every post about it that i found here.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
from math import pi
def acirc(r):
    pi*r**2

def madeiratotal(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5):

    a = acirc(r1)
    b = acirc(r2)
    c = acirc(r3)
    d = acirc(r4)
    e = acirc(r5)

    print (a+b+c+d+e)

madeiratotal(0.15,0.09,0.175,0.1,0.115)
```

I already try defining the "acirc" function inside the "madeiratotal" function, try to print all numbers separated and them suming then... I just don't know what else to do please help

Comment: You need to actually return a value from `acirc()` with `return pi*r**2`

Comment: but what if i don't want the value to pop in the screen?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `pop in the screen`

Comment: i thought that the return was only used when i wanted the value to appear on the screen. in this case i just wanted the function to do the math but not showing the results on the screen. Anyway i understood what was wrong, thank you!!

Comment: I take it you're running this code from an interactive python shell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value from acirc function otherwise return type is None

```
def acirc(r):
    return pi*r**2
```